# purpose of brew update before brew install

Tags: macos, homebrew

Most places recommend running a brew update before a brew install. as such:

`brew update`
`brew install <package_name>`

What is the purpose of first running a brew update?
I've done installs without updates several times and it worked fine

Answer (score 6):

You don't really need to do `brew update` before `brew install`. The `brew install` command automatically updates the resources (that's what `brew update` does) before installing anything.